# Is it possible to bundle python code with tkinter and sqlite3 database package to an exe executable file

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

so, Another problem I came across with Tkinter & Python is that I don't find it possible to bundle an entire set of code with tkinter and sqlite 3 database to an exe file so it can be shared. Everytime, I do so the exe file won't run properly. Is even doing this possible or do I have to move out from SQLite3 completely.

```
  # Core Packages
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.scrolledtext import *
import tkinter.filedialog
from tkcalendar import Calendar, DateEntry
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkintertable import TableCanvas, TableModel
from tkinter import ttk

# Database
import sqlite3
import csv


conn = sqlite3.connect('data.db')
c = conn.cursor()

def create_table():
    c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS usersdata(firstname TEXT,lastname TEXT,email TEXT,age TEXT,date_of_birth TEXT,address TEXT,phonenumber REAL)')


def add_data(firstname,lastname,email,age,date_of_birth,address,phonenumber):
    c.execute('INSERT INTO usersdata(firstname ,lastname ,email ,age,date_of_birth,address,phonenumber ) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)',(firstname,lastname,email,age,date_of_birth,address,phonenumber))
    conn.commit()


def view_all_users():
    c.execute('SELECT * FROM usersdata')
    data = c.fetchall()
    # for row in data:
    #   print(row)
    # return data
    for row in data:
        print(row)
        tree.insert("", tk.END, values=row)
    # tab2_display.insert(tk.END,data)

def view_all_details():
    c.execute('SELECT * FROM usersdata')
    data = c.fetchall()
    # for row in data:
    #   print(row)
    # return data
    for row in data:
        # print(row)
        # tree.insert("", tk.END, values=row)
        tab2_display.insert("",tk.END,row)  

def get_single_user(firstname):
    c.execute('SELECT * FROM usersdata WHERE firstname="{}"'.format(firstname))
    data = c.fetchall()
    # tab2_display.insert(tk.END,data)
    return data

def edit_single_user(firstname,new_name):
    c.execute('UPDATE usersdata SET firstname ="{}" WHERE firstname="{}"'.format(new_name,firstname
        ))
    conn.commit()
    data = c.fetchall()
    return data
def delete_single_user(firstname):
    c.execute('DELETE FROM usersdata WHERE firstname="{}"'.format(firstname))
    conn.commit()


def view_all_data():
    c.execute('SELECT * FROM usersdata')
    data = c.fetchall()
    # for row in data:
    #   print(row)
    # result = [ row for row in data ]
    # return result
    
    


create_table()

 # Structure and Layout
window = Tk()
window.title("Registrio GUI")
window.geometry("750x450")
window.config(background='black')

style = ttk.Style(window)
style.configure('lefttab.TNotebook', tabposition='wn',)


# TAB LAYOUT
tab_control = ttk.Notebook(window,style='lefttab.TNotebook')
 
tab1 = ttk.Frame(tab_control)
tab2 = ttk.Frame(tab_control)
tab3 = ttk.Frame(tab_control)
tab4 = ttk.Frame(tab_control)
tab5 = ttk.Frame(tab_control)
tab6 = ttk.Frame(tab_control)

# ADD TABS TO NOTEBOOK
tab_control.add(tab1, text=f'{"Home":^20s}')
tab_control.add(tab2, text=f'{"View":^20s}')
tab_control.add(tab3, text=f'{"Search":^20s}')
tab_control.add(tab4, text=f'{"Edit":^20s}')
tab_control.add(tab5, text=f'{"Export":^20s}')
tab_control.add(tab6, text=f'{"About ":^20s}')


label1 = Label(tab1, text= 'Registrio GUI',padx=5, pady=5)
label1.grid(column=0, row=0)
 
label2 = Label(tab2, text= 'View',padx=5, pady=5)
label2.grid(column=0, row=0)

label3 = Label(tab3, text= 'Search',padx=5, pady=5)
label3.grid(column=0, row=0)

label4 = Label(tab4, text= 'Edit/Update',padx=5, pady=5)
label4.grid(column=0, row=0)

label5 = Label(tab5, text= 'Export',padx=5, pady=5)
label5.grid(column=0, row=0)

label6 = Label(tab6, text= 'About',padx=5, pady=5)
label6.grid(column=0, row=0)

tab_control.pack(expand=1, fill='both')


# Functions
def clear_text():
    entry_fname.delete('0',END)
    entry_lname.delete('0',END)
    entry_email.delete('0',END)
    entry_age.delete('0',END)
    entry_address.delete('0',END)
    entry_phone.delete('0',END)

def add_details():
    firstname = str(entry_fname.get())
    lastname = str(entry_lname.get())
    email = str(entry_email.get())
    age = str(entry_age.get())
    date_of_birth = str(cal.get())
    phone_number = str(entry_phone.get())
    address = str(entry_address.get())
    add_data(firstname,lastname,email,age,date_of_birth,address,phone_number)
    result = '\nFirst Name:{},\nLast Name:{},\nEmail:{},\nAge:{},\nDate of Birth:{},\nPhone Number:{},\nAddress:{}\n'.format(firstname,lastname,email,age,date_of_birth,phone_number,address)
    tab1_display.insert(tk.END,result)
    messagebox.showinfo(title = "Registrio GUI", message = "Submitted to DataBase")

def clear_display_result():
    tab1_display.delete('1.0',END)


def search_user_by_name():
    firstname = str(entry_search.get())
    result = get_single_user(firstname)
    # c.execute('SELECT * FROM usersdata WHERE firstname="{}"'.format(firstname))
    # data = c.fetchall()
    # print(result)
    tab2_display.insert(tk.END,result)


def clear_display_view():
    tab2_display.delete('1.0',END)


def clear_entered_search():
    entry_search.delete('0',END)

def clear_tree_view():
    # tab2_display.delete('1.0',END)
    tree.delete('1.0',END)


def export_as_csv():
    filename = str(entry_filename.get())
    myfilename = filename + '.csv'
    with open(myfilename, 'w') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        c.execute('SELECT * FROM usersdata')
        data = c.fetchall()
        writer.writerow(['firstname','lastname','email','age','date_of_birth','address','phonenumber'])
        writer.writerows(data)
        messagebox.showinfo(title = "Registrio GUI", message = '"Exported As {}"'.format(myfilename))

def export_as_xls():
    pass




# Main Home Registration
l1 = Label(tab1,text="First Name",padx=5,pady=5)
l1.grid(column=0,row=1)
fname_raw_entry = StringVar()
entry_fname = Entry(tab1,textvariable=fname_raw_entry,width=50)
entry_fname.grid(row=1,column=1)

l2 = Label(tab1,text="Last Name",padx=5,pady=5)
l2.grid(column=0,row=2)
lname_raw_entry = StringVar()
entry_lname = Entry(tab1,textvariable=lname_raw_entry,width=50)
entry_lname.grid(row=2,column=1)

l3 = Label(tab1,text="Email",padx=5,pady=5)
l3.grid(column=0,row=3)
email_raw_entry = StringVar()
entry_email = Entry(tab1,textvariable=email_raw_entry,width=50)
entry_email.grid(row=3,column=1)


l4 = Label(tab1,text="Age",padx=5,pady=5)
l4.grid(column=0,row=4)
raw_entry = IntVar()
entry_age = Entry(tab1,textvariable=raw_entry,width=50)
entry_age.grid(row=4,column=1)

l5 = Label(tab1,text="Date of Birth",padx=5,pady=5)
l5.grid(column=0,row=5)
dob_raw_entry = StringVar()
cal = DateEntry(tab1, width=30,textvariable=dob_raw_entry, background='darkblue',foreground='white', borderwidth=2, year=2010)
cal.grid(row=5,column=1,padx=10, pady=10)


l6 = Label(tab1,text="Address",padx=5,pady=5)
l6.grid(column=0,row=6)
address_raw_entry = StringVar()
entry_address = Entry(tab1,textvariable=address_raw_entry,width=50)
entry_address.grid(row=6,column=1)


l7 = Label(tab1,text="Phone Number",padx=5,pady=5)
l7.grid(column=0,row=7)
phone_raw_entry = StringVar()
entry_phone = Entry(tab1,textvariable=phone_raw_entry,width=50)
entry_phone.grid(row=7,column=1)

button1 = Button(tab1,text="Clear",width=12,bg='#03A9F4',fg='#fff',command=clear_text)
button1.grid(row=8,column=0,padx=10,pady=10)


button2 = Button(tab1,text="Add",width=12,bg='#03A9F4',fg='#fff',command=add_details)
button2.grid(row=8,column=1,padx=10,pady=10)


# Display Screen For Result
tab1_display = ScrolledText(tab1,height=5)
tab1_display.grid(row=10,column=0, columnspan=3,padx=5,pady=5)
button3 = Button(tab1,text="Clear Result",width=12,bg='#03A9F4',fg='#fff',command=clear_display_result)
button3.grid(row=12,column=1,padx=10,pady=10)


# View 
# label_view1 = Label(tab2,text="Search Name",padx=5,pady=5)
# label_view1.grid(column=0,row=2)
# search_raw_entry = StringVar()
# entry_search = Entry(tab2,textvariable=search_raw_entry,width=30)
# entry_search.grid(row=2,column=1)

button_view2 = Button(tab2,text="View All",width=12,bg='#03A9F4',fg='#fff',command=view_all_users)
button_view2.grid(row=1,column=0,padx=10,pady=10)

# button_view3 = Button(tab2,text="Clear Search",width=12,bg='#03A9F4',fg='#fff',command=clear_entered_search)
# button_view3.grid(row=1,column=1,padx=10,pady=10)

# button_view4 = Button(tab2,text="Clear Results",width=12,bg='#03A9F4',fg='#fff',command=clear_tree_view)
# button_view4.grid(row=1,column=2,padx=10,pady=10)

# button_view5 = Button(tab2,text="Search",width=12,bg='#03A9F4',fg='#fff',command=search_user_by_name)
# button_view5.grid(row=2,column=2,padx=10,pady=10)


tree= ttk.Treeview(tab2, column=("column1", "column2", "column3","column4", "column5","column6", "column7"), show='headings')
tree.heading("#1", text="First Name")
tree.heading("#2", text="Last Name")
tree.heading("#3", text="")
tree.heading("#1", text="NUMBER")
tree.heading("#2", text="FIRST NAME")
tree.heading("#3", text="SURNAME")
tree.heading('#7',text="Phone Number")
tree.grid(row=10,column=0, columnspan=3,padx=5,pady=5)

# Search
label_view1 = Label(tab3,text="Search Name",padx=5,pady=5)
label_view1.grid(column=0,row=1)
search_raw_entry = StringVar()
entry_search = Entry(tab3,textvariable=search_raw_entry,width=30)
entry_search.grid(row=1,column=1)

# button_view2 = Button(tab3,text="View All",width=12,bg='#03A9F4',fg='#fff',command=view_all_details)
# button_view2.grid(row=1,column=0,padx=10,pady=10)

button_view3 = Button(tab3,text="Clear Search",width=12,bg='#03A9F4',fg='#fff',command=clear_entered_search)
button_view3.grid(row=2,column=1,padx=10,pady=10)

button_view4 = Button(tab3,text="Clear Results",width=12,bg='#03A9F4',fg='#fff',command=clear_display_view)
button_view4.grid(row=2,column=2,padx=10,pady=10)

button_view5 = Button(tab3,text="Search",width=12,bg='#03A9F4',fg='#fff',command=search_user_by_name)
button_view5.grid(row=1,column=2,padx=10,pady=10)

tab2_display = ScrolledText(tab3,height=5)
# tab2_display = Listbox(tab2,height=5,width=60)
tab2_display.grid(row=10,column=0, columnspan=3,padx=5,pady=5)
# tree= ttk.Treeview(tab3, column=("column1", "column2", "column3","column4", "column5","column6", "column7"), show='headings')
# tree.heading("#1", text="First Name")
# tree.heading("#2", text="Last Name")
# tree.heading("#3", text="")
# tree.heading("#1", text="NUMBER")
# tree.heading("#2", text="FIRST NAME")
# tree.heading("#3", text="SURNAME")
# tree.heading('#7',text="Phone Number")
# tree.grid(row=10,column=0, columnspan=3,padx=5,pady=5)


# Export Database

label_export1 = Label(tab5,text="File Name",padx=5,pady=5)
label_export1.grid(column=0,row=2)
filename_raw_entry = StringVar()
entry_filename = Entry(tab5,textvariable=filename_raw_entry,width=30)
entry_filename.grid(row=2,column=1)

button_export3 = Button(tab5,text="To CSV",width=12,bg='#03A9F4',fg='#fff',command=export_as_csv)
button_export3.grid(row=3,column=1,padx=10,pady=10)

button_export3 = Button(tab5,text="To XLS",width=12,bg='#03A9F4',fg='#fff',command=export_as_xls)
button_export3.grid(row=3,column=2,padx=10,pady=10)


data = {'rec1': {'col1': 99.88, 'col2': 108.79, 'label': 'rec1'},
       'rec2': {'col1': 99.88, 'col2': 108.79, 'label': 'rec2'}
       }
# data2 = view_all_data()
table = TableCanvas(tab4,data=data)
table.show()


# About TAB
about_label = Label(tab6,text="",pady=5,padx=5)
about_label.grid(column=0,row=1)



window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is totally possible to make an executable using Tkinter and SQLite. I usually use `Pyinstaller` for this purpose (see https://www.pyinstaller.org/ and https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ for full details).

Once you install `Pyinstaller` in your virtual environment, you should create a file `main.spec` with the following format so that you have enough freedom to fully customize your exe file. Depending on your code, you may need less or more features:

```
# -*- mode: python -*-
import os

block_cipher = None

current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.curdir)

a = Analysis(['main.py'],
             # pathex=['output_path'],
             pathex=[current_dir],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[
                 ('img/*.png', 'img'),
                 ('inputs/*.csv', 'inputs'),
                 ('databases/*.db', 'databases'),
                 ('settings.ini', '.'),
             ],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher)

pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
          cipher=block_cipher)

exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          Tree('documentation/_build/html', prefix='documentation/_build/html/'),
          name='Project Name',
          debug=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=False)
```

You should properly set the `output_path` and the `Project Name`. Moreover, this script assumes that your main file is called `main.py`, but you can change this as well. As you can see, in this case, I bundle all the images, csv files, databases (SQLite) and even documentation created from Sphinx.

Then, you have to call the following command:

```
path_to_pyinstaller/pyinstaller --onefile main.spec --key your_key
```

Where `path_to_pyinstaller` is the path where Pyinstaller has been installed under your virtualenv. You have to also set `your_key`.

There are other libraries that could be also used, such as `cx_Freeze`, but again, I usually use `Pyinstaller`.

It is important to bear in mind that, when bundling, some errors related to relative paths may arise. My solution for this is to define a function `resource_path` like this:

```
import sys

# Get the absolute path
def resource_path(relative_path):
    """ Get absolute path to resource, works for dev and for PyInstaller """
    try:
        # PyInstaller creates a temp folder and stores path in _MEIPASS
        base_path = sys._MEIPASS
    except Exception as e:
        # print(e)
        base_path = os.path.abspath(".")

    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)
```

Then, you should use this function when calling any image, file, or database. For instance, when connecting to SQLite, you should do as follows:

```
import sqlite3

self.conn = sqlite3.connect(resource_path(database_path))
```

Where `database_path` is the relative path to the database.

Comment: I believe I have tried this method, but it does not seem to work when there is sqlite3 inside of it. the exe file does not execute. it says fail to execute when trying this

Comment: when i click the .exe file. it comes with a popup saying the script failed to execute. however, when I do it with a non sqlite3 python code it seems to run fine.

Comment: I guess, an error should appear when running the command I mentioned. Maybe you could provide us that error.... Also ensure that you include all databases under `data` variable of main.spec file.

Comment: @powerlordx1, I have added an important function that you should call to avoid problems iwth relative/absolute paths. Try to call it in your code and see if the exe works.

Comment: Ok thanks. I have went back and made these changes, but when I bundled it to an exe, the exe file just opens a blank screen

Comment: Could you provide the log when you build the exe file? Maybe you could include it in a separate question too...

Comment: I used pyinstaller --onefile FORMS.PY main.spec --key 123456 . The command runs and creates an exe file, but the exe file won't work

Comment: yep, it created the dist file and i clicked .exe and it just comes with a blank screen

Comment: Humm that's strange. What I can say you is that sometimes I have faced this issue, but I have always solved it ensuring that all the paths of the code (image, database, logo...) are written using the function `resource_path` that I have provided. Please ensure that all the paths use this function. If you cannot solve it this way, I can create a chat and you could provide me exactly your code so that I can try it...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219764/discussion-between-powerlordx1-and-david-duran).